# .htaccess redirect - changing file name and query string order

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have to redirect my pages as follow:

if I have

```
mysite.com/abc.php?id=12345
```

I have to redirect to

```
mysite.com/def/12345.html
```

if I have

```
mysite.com/abc.php?id=55626
```

I have to redirect to

```
mysite.com/def/55626.html
```

Please advise

=====================================================

The following code solved my problem

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^abc\.php$ http://mysite.com/def/%1.html? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: What did you try so far, and what was wrong with it?

Comment: The use of `.php` indicates to me, as a viewer, that there's PHP script driving the thing. So why are you using `.htaccess` rather than `header()`?

Comment: I have no experience with redirect rules.
Both abc.php and def are .php files. 12345.html is query string.
I need my paths look like a static pages with .html bu it still .php file

Comment: @lgal: Please answer my questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^def/([^/]+).html /abc.php?section=$1 [NC]
```